# Java pattern to find repeated groups

Tags: java, regex

I would like to get the repeated part in a recurring fraction. For example if the fraction is 0.6666667, I would like to get 0.67 and the repeated part (6) or for 0.36363636 0.36 and (36) as a matcher group. I tried using capturing groups in Java but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Here's what I have right now:

```
String patt = "(.+?)\\1+";
```

Unfortunately this matches 0.003003003 as "0". Is there any way to get "003" here?

Comment: That's not a valid regex to begin with. You can't start with a `?` quantifier.

Comment: I played around with it and have something halfway working. Edited in answer.

Comment: This problem is no task for regex I think. First there can be a "prefix", e.g. 1/15 = 0.0666...7 (prefix = 0.0), then we have to take into account that the last cipher is rounded. If you have 0.163163... then this might end in 2 (rounding) or 6, no full repetition... another problem with regex. A sophisticated function which analyses the String is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the underlying problem you're trying to solve.
It appears what you want to do is not text-fiddling but *rounding*.

Try this:

```
BigDecimal r = new BigDecimal("0.66666667").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(r);
```

It will show:

```
0.67
```

Similarly, for `0.363636...` it will give you `0.36` and so on.

If you really want to go with regex, and all your inputs have `0` before the decimal point, you could perhaps try

```
0\.(.+?)\\1+
```

Answer (score 0):

`"(.+)\\1+"` should find `003` taking the longest sequence at index 2.